# Can only visit certain sites using Internet Explorer 11

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11

I rarely use IE so I was surprised that when I loaded IE 11 that I had trouble navigating the Internet. I can visit some sites, and not others. And there are no error messages or popups as far as I can tell. For instance I can browse MSN or the eMachines website, but not Google or Microsoft Labs Online.

The only extensions I have are LastPass, Java, and Adobe PDF Link Helper.

I have no idea what to do. I need it to work for a lab assignment.

Comment: What does it say when you try to visit google? Have you tried a different browser such as chrome or Firefox? What happens with the other browsers?

Comment: people still use internet explorer? WHYYYYYYYYYYYY

Comment: @sickest there is nothing wrong with IE11

Comment: Chrome works fine. Haven't tried Firefox. There is no error message when trying to visit Google. No 403 or 404 message. It just stays at the previous page and does nothing. I forgot to add that I am running Windows 7 x64. Usually I use Chrome but I have to use IE for a school assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting Internet Explorer seemed to do the trick.